# Issues with UISplitViewController and modal UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a really strange UI glitch in my iPhone/iPad app. Because I wanted to find the cause of it, I created a new project with as little code as possible. The important code is below.

Basically, I have a `UISplitViewController` containing two `UIViewController` subclasses. When a button is tapped, the first one presents modally and as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` a `UIViewController` subclass called `Modal`. In there, when a button is tapped, another `UIViewController` subclass called `Text` is presented, this time as `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`. In `Text`, there is a `UITextView`. When it is tapped, everything is alright, but when the iPad is rotated, I get this:

[image]

The white part is the `Text` view controller, the red part in the background is `ViewControllerTwo`.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? And what I can do to fix it?

---

Here is the Project: [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?gb2u6yemj4x6rtz)

---

Here is the relevant source code:

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ViewControllerOne *one = [[ViewControllerOne alloc] init];
    ViewControllerTwo *two = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] init];

    UISplitViewController *split = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    split.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, two, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = split;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

// ViewControllerOne.m

#import "Modal.h"

@implementation ViewControllerOne

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 44, 44);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonTapped
{
    Modal *modalOne = [[Modal alloc] init];
    modalOne.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:modalOne animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{ 
    return YES;
}

// Modal.m

#import "Text.h"

@implementation Modal

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *buttonOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonOne.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 44, 44);
    buttonOne.tag = 1;
    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *buttonTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 44, 44);
    buttonTwo.tag = 2;
    [buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:buttonOne];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonTwo];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (button.tag == 1)
    {
        Text *text = [[Text alloc] init];
        text.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentModalViewController:text animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{ 
    return YES;
}

// Text.m

@implementation Text

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{ 
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a download link for a sample project that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @SebastianCelis Uploaded it now, see the question.

Comment: Your archive fails to build. It references files outside of your project.

Comment: @SebastianCelis Hope it works now. Forgot to "Copy items into destination group's folder"...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to present the modal views from the UISplitViewController instead of it's subviews...

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController];

[splitViewController presentModalViewController:modal animated:YES];
```